# why My resized Image size is not what I want and expect?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want image width and height 250 while image is resizing into 250X150? but why?
Here is my **controller** code

```
$config =  array(
          'image_library'   => 'gd2',
          'source_image'    =>  $data['full_path'],
          'maintain_ratio'  =>  TRUE,
          'width'           =>  250,
          'height'          =>  250,
        );
        $this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: If it is literally rendering 150 in the source and not a css override my guess is the maintain_ratio maybe at play here. Try setting that to False just for a quick sanity check.

Comment: You are using maintain ratio, this will most likely not crop an image but set the longest side to 250 and use the ratio to calculate the other length.

Comment: even I disabled the Maintain_ratio still same output..

Answer (score 0):

thanks  **Adrianopolis**, it works.
I **changed** This code

```
$config =  array(
      'image_library'   => 'gd2',
      'source_image'    =>  $data['full_path'],
      'maintain_ratio'  =>  TRUE,
      'width'           =>  250,
      'height'          =>  250,
    );
    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
```

**`Into`**

```
$config =  array(
      'image_library'   => 'gd2',
      'source_image'    =>  $data['full_path'],
      'maintain_ratio'  =>  FALSE,
      'width'           =>  250,
      'height'          =>  250,
    );
    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
```